# Active Records method SELECT

Tags: php, class, oop

I try to emulate the active records pattern in the users class.
Show below the code in exam.

```
Codice PHP:
//method
    public function getUtenti($criteria = NULL ,$value = NULL){ 
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM utenti "; 
        $sql.="LEFT JOIN tecnici ON tec_idtecnico = idutente "; 
        if($criteria != "") 
            $sql.="WHERE ".$criteria; 
        return $this->db->fetchAll($sql,$value); 
    } 

//metodo db 
    public function fetchAll($sql, array $params = array()){  
        return $this->executeQuery($sql, $params)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    }  

//method for get users 

foreach($user->getUtenti('flagamm = :flagamm', array('flagamm' => 'x')) as $rk){ 
   echo "<option value=\"".$rk['idutente']."\">".$rk['tec_ragionesociale']."</option>"; 
                                                }
```

I have a question on the select method "`getUtenti()"`.

Is correct send at method the variable `$criteria` (that contains the where condition) and `$value` (that contains the array value for build sql)?

The problem born when i build the query with `$_POST`.

In this way i can't control value first build query...

Another solution in my mind is create an obj `$user`, use method `set()` of each variable, that contains all control for variable, but when i invoke `getUtenti()` i don't know how can build where condition...

i don't know how can build the query. 
example:

```
$user = new user(); 
$user->setCompany($_POST['company']);//set the property , in this method i control the leng, make trim ecc ecc. 
$set->GetUser(); //this method should give me back all users filters with company
```

but how build the method GetUser()? 
I could do it this way in the method GetUsers()

```
$sql = "SELECT * Users ";
if($this->company != "") 
   $sql.="WHERE company = ".$this->company;
```

but i can't decide the comparison operators =, !=, <, > ecc

Comment: You say the problem is with how you build a query from your $_POST variables.  Can you show what you've tried in this, and maybe we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: I have edit the principal post, is correct?